# In php how to get date array from a custom set of cycle

Tags: php, datetime

I have created a table for working days for a month, in other table i have set a cycle as  -

- 1 = Mon
- 2 = Tue
- 3 = Wed
- 4 = Thu
- 5 = Fri
- 6 = Sat
- 7 = Sun

if cycle is 10,15 or any thing, how can i get the day for a month? please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$cycle = 10;
$days = array(1 => 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun');
$dayNo = $cycle % 7;
echo $days[$dayNo]; // => Wed
```

Comment: Hi Amal, if for Month Jan 2014 cycle day is 1 (Mon) and cycle length is 10 then i want to display date 13th Jan to 17th Jan (cycle 1) AND 20th Jan to 24th Jan (Cycle 2).. how can i get this

Comment: @RajatTripathi: That's a different problem, so [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Make sure you clearly explain what you're trying to achieve, include **your attempts**, why it isn't working and the expected output.

Comment: please check this new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920453/in-php-how-to-get-date-array-from-a-custom-set-of-cycle-and-cycle-length